# Simple Multithreading Question

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

Ok I should already know the answer but...

I want to execute a number of different tasks in parallel on a separate thread and wait for the execution of all threads to finish before continuing. I am aware that I could have used the `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem()` or the `BackgroundWorker` but did not want to use either (for no particular reason).

So is the code below the correct way to execute tasks in parallel on a background thread and wait for them to finish processing?

```
Thread[] threads = new Thread[3];
for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
{
    threads[i] = new Thread(SomeActionDelegate);
    threads[i].Start();

}

for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
{
    threads[i].Join();
}
```

I know this question must have been asked 100 times before so thanks for your answer and patience.

Comment: Spawning new threads is costly so you generally want to avoid doing so for short running tasks.

Comment: @Brian I completely agree, thanks for the reminder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is a correct way to do this. But if `SomeActionDelegate` is relatively small then the overhead of creating 3 threads will be significant. That's why you probaly should use the ThreadPool anyway. Even though it has no clean equivalent to Join.

A BackgroundWorker is mainly useful when interacting with the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It's always hard to say what the "correct" way is, but your approach does work correctly.

However, by using `Join`, the UI thread (if the main thread is a UI thread) will be blocked, therefore freezing the UI. If that is not the case, your approach is basically OK, even if it has different problems (scalability/number of concurrent threads, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

if your are (or will  be using .Net 4.0) try using [Task parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(VS.100).aspx)

Comment: Yep can't wait till .NET 4 is officially released